# Problems while trying to connect to database Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm trying to connect to database and my request had to create a table and add values to it. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and i created a database named "itstep" in Databases folder.

```
------- HibernateMain.java ------ 

public class HibernateMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Color color = new Color(Collections.singletonList("red"),true, Collections.singletonMap("r",55));
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(color);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    System.exit(0);
 }
}

------- HibernateUtil.java ------ 
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {// Create properties for Hibernate configuration
        Properties hibernateProps = new Properties();
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itstep");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.USER, "sa");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.PASS, "");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");


        // Build the configuration object and register entity classes
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperties(hibernateProps);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Color.class);
        // Build the ServiceRegistry and create the SessionFactory
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory; }}



------- Color.java ------ 

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="color")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Color implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private List<String> colors;
    @Column
    private boolean primary;
    @Column
    private Map<String,Integer> rgb = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public Color(List<String> colors, boolean primary, Map<String, Integer> rgb) {
        this.colors = colors;
        this.primary = primary;
        this.rgb = rgb;
    }
}



------- pom.xml ------ 
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
   v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Lab2.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Archetype - Lab2.0</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

When i'm trying to activate Main file, i get:

```
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to 
create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at itstep.task_6.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:37)
    at itstep.task_6.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    at itstep.task_6.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service 
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 .......
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load 
class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
.......
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
......
```

What could be a problem? Maybe improper configuration?

-----UPDATED------
After all recommended actions:

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot 
invoke 
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProvi 
    derImpl$PooledConnections.poll()" because "this.pool" is null
     бер. 28, 2023 1:08:24 ДП org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
     INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
     бер. 28, 2023 1:08:24 ДП 
      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl 
makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was 
null
бер. 28, 2023 1:08:24 ДП 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
бер. 28, 2023 1:08:24 ДП 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has 
failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the 
connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is 
running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make 
sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Initial SessionFactory creation 
failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create 
requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create 
requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
.......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error 
calling Driver#connect
.......
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP 
connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: 
"Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection 
properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the 
host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP 
connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Comment: Just one thing - maybe not the only thing: You have `jdbc:mysql` for MySQL but also you have `com.microsoft.sqlserver` and `dialect.SQLServerDialect` for SQL Server - two different databases. (Maybe you are also missing the relevant JDBC JAR file for SQL Server).

Comment: The url for sql server usually looks like: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=itstep

Comment: Also, you don't have dependency to sql server but to mysql. The correct maven is something like: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.jre11</version>
</dependency>

Comment: check updated pls